# Is this acceptable usage when frustrated with a web page: "It won't click"

Tags: word-usage

My buddy was trying to click something on a webpage and he said "It won't click."  As a programmer, I know that what he meant was "The event triggered by the onClick handler is not happening."  Given this, is it appropriate to say "It won't click" or is there something else to say there like "This link is broken."

Would it change if it were a form's submit button vs. a regular blue anchor tag?

Comment: NB: this is an example of middle voice. *I can't click the link* is active, *The link can't be clicked* is passive, and *The link won't click* is middle: grammatically active but semantically passive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*It won't click* is playfully colloquial, but I think it's fine. It's almost as if you're making the virtual button into a physical object. If it were a physical button, you'd say "it won't press." In that case, you would literally be saying that the button wasn't depressing. *It won't click* plays on that.

My first choice would be *it won't respond*. This would work for normal links or other buttons. Also, *it won't recognize the click* could work.

Comment: +1 for a much better way to state the same meaning, but no accept because it doesn't address if the first way is grammatically eligible albeit awkward and somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Oops, I didn't fully read the question. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't the button be receiving the click, though, and hence wouldn't "the button won't be clicked" or "the button won't be pressed" make more sense? Granted, your "it won't respond" answer sounds much better than either of those, and your "it won't recognize the click" not only makes sense, but is more accurate than either.

Answer (score 2):

I think a more useful phrase for the developer, and one that would be plausibly plain-English enough to come out of the mouth of an end-user would be this:

***"Nothing happens when I click the link/button."***

Comment: My buddy was on some major website, not something I made; I asked "what's taking so long?" and he said, "It won't click."  I have heard others say it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it makes much sense now, I can see this becoming standard phrasing. I think it's probably pretty rare now for people to think of clicking as something they do *to* the mouse. They are clicking the on-screen element *with* the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

In a conversation about a software system between people familiar with the source code, it is useful to use method calls as verbs, even when their normal definition does not match the meaning in this particular context. For example, "the object does not validate" instead of "the object's validate method returns false".

When talking to a wider audience (i.e. anyone not familiar with the source code) it is advisable to avoid jargon as far as possible, and use terms and phrases that are widely understood. When considering acceptability to a wider audience, we can look at prescriptive language rules, and observed general usage patterns.

From a prescriptive perspective, when talking about clicking an item in an electronic interface, click should normally be used as a transitive verb, i.e. "the user clicks an item", or "the user clicks on an item".

However, when used as an intransitive verb, click has meanings that could make sense in your scenario. If the interface is expected to give audible feedback when selecting an item, then it would be perfectly acceptable to complain when it "does not click".
Other meanings of click as an intransitive verb include "function smoothly", or "succeed", but these would perhaps be better applied to overall functioning of a system, rather than a single action within it.

It is certainly possible that your phrase may gain acceptance as a way of describing the failure of an item in a user interface to respond to being clicked on. In fact extending a transitive verb with an intransitive usage seems to be popular. For example, while "validate" is normally a transitive verb, it is very common for people to use it intransitively (e.g. "My ticket won't validate.").

Given the above, I would surmise that this usage of "It won't click" could be judged an acceptable colloquialism. Personally, I would prefer to say "It does not respond when I click on it."

Sources: Merriam-Webster definitions of ["click"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/click) and ["validate"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/validate).

Tangentially, unless debugging or logging, saying the event triggered by the OnClick handler is not happening is guessing the fault from the symptom. Maybe there is no event registered. Maybe the handler is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your buddy said should work. If you define *it* as *my clicking the element* and *click* as *triggering the event handler* as bound by jquery, then the sentence

> It won't click.

Should mean:

> My clicking the element won't trigger the event handler.

It's a bit complicated but I believe it to be grammatical. The important part is that `.click()` is waiting for the click event, which unfortunately isn't triggered by your clicking the element. If those conditions are understood, the sentence should work.

Comment: It could also mean "clicking on the element doesn't have any effect."

Comment: _it_ is the element itself.  "The element won't .click()!" is what I think my friend is saying - he just doesn't know thats what he means.